# How to cancel the function of showing copy button in UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

And when I click a image in my imageView , I found that showing a copy button around the image , how to cancel it , Thank you very much!

Comment: What comes before "And"?

Comment: because after click the image I want to show a large pic , so I didn't want the copy button around the image to show , I think this function maybe the default for iamgeView , but how to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use UIButton, instead of UIImageView?
You can set button to be represented as image. And also, can define custom click method, where you can load different (larger) pic...

Something like this:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(loadLargerImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Thank you first. I have found the answer:-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
 if ([UIMenuController sharedMenuController])
 {
  [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
  
 }
 
 return NO;
}

Comment: ok, np, dude. I thought that you need to have some custom action, on image click (loading larger pic).